# make a single array using php

Tags: php, arrays

How to make it as one array using PHP ?

```
["08:00 AM","08:15 AM","08:30 AM","08:45 AM"]
["09:00 AM","09:15 AM","09:30 AM","09:45 AM"]
["10:00 AM","10:15 AM","10:30 AM","10:45 AM"]
["11:00 AM","11:15 AM","11:30 AM","11:45 AM"]
["04:00 PM","04:15 PM","04:30 PM","04:45 PM"]
["05:00 PM","05:15 PM","05:30 PM","05:45 PM"]
["06:00 PM","06:15 PM","06:30 PM","06:45 PM"]
```

I want combine these array into one array like this

```
["08:00 AM","08:15 AM","08:30 AM","08:45 AM",
 "09:00 AM","09:15 AM","09:30 AM","09:45 AM",
 "10:00 AM","10:15 AM","10:30 AM","10:45 AM",
 "11:00 AM","11:15 AM","11:30 AM","11:45 AM",
 "04:00 PM","04:15 PM","04:30 PM","04:45 PM",
 "05:00 PM","05:15 PM","05:30 PM","05:45 PM",
"06:00 PM","06:15 PM","06:30 PM","06:45 PM"]
```

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: i want combine multiple array into single

Answer (score 4):

You the `...` operator (PHP 5.6 and above [variadic functions operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.variadics)) with [array-merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

```
$arr = array(["aaa", "bbb"],["ccc","ddd"]);
$arr = array_merge(...$arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the global built-in [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) function.

Comment: it is better if you provide some code.